# Does reverse biased diode have threshold voltage and static resistance?

Tags: diodes, reverse-bias

If a diode is reverse biased, will the diode have threshold voltage and static resistance?

Comment: Can you clarify this question? What do you mean by a "threshold voltage" and "static resistance"? Have you read something about this that is confusing?

Comment: A warm welcome to the site. Please note that it's not a free design house, homework-answering service or on-line technical encyclopedia, copied out to you on demand. People will help you take the next step if your question shows you've done as much as you possibly could on your own - which yours doesn't, I'm afraid. This is one line expecting mountains of effort in reply for free. Please edit your question and greatly improve it. Show your own work and own findings so far in considerable detail. The better the quality of question, the better the quality of the answers you will attract.

Answer (score 2):

In forward conduction, a diode is often very crudely modelled as having a theshhold voltage and a static resistance. These are often accurate enough for designing bias circuits with them, but not for accurate work, and they don't help with understanding what a diode is or how it works.

In reverse blocking, the appropriate simple model is a leakage current and a breakdown voltage.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to both questions is "no".